# Regarding Multiple Apk On The Basis Of Arm

Tags: android, google-play

My one application is published on google play which is support arm6 cpu architecture.Now i want to update my application for arm7 user with some given functionality but still want to retain arm6 cpu user so he could also download app which was compatible with arm6.I have doubt suppose again  in future i upload application with arm6 cpu compatible with same  package name  so what should be show to arm7 user in future.It will be show latest arm6 app or past arm7 application .

Please help !!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CpuArchOptions

Comment: I have check it but they are not mention about this case